# How do I change the display attribute when a value is over 30

Tags: javascript, project

I have a image of a crown that i want to appear when the total score of one of the team gets to 30. this is my code in java.
You see the code for the appearing image at the end.

```
let homePoints = document.getElementById("homep");
let guestPoints = document.getElementById("guestp");
let counthomePoints = 0;
let countguestPoints = 0;
var h = document.getElementById("hw");
var g = document.getElementById("gw");

function haddone() {
  counthomePoints += 1;
  homePoints.textContent = counthomePoints;
}
function haddtwo() {
  counthomePoints += 2;
  homePoints.textContent = counthomePoints;
}
function haddthree() {
  counthomePoints += 3;
  homePoints.textContent = counthomePoints;
}
function gaddone() {
  countguestPoints += 1;
  guestPoints.textContent = countguestPoints;
}
function gaddtwo() {
  countguestPoints += 2;
  guestPoints.textContent = countguestPoints;
}
function gaddthree() {
  countguestPoints += 3;
  guestPoints.textContent = countguestPoints;
}

function res() {
  counthomePoints = 0;
  countguestPoints = 0;
  guestPoints.textContent = 0;
  homePoints.textContent = 0;
}
if (counthomePoints >>> 29) {
  h.style.display = "block";
} else {
  h.style.display = "none";
}
```

I tried this code and expected that when counthomePoints gets over 29 the style.display of the h element would change to "block" and if not over 29 it will be "none"

```
if (counthomePoints > 29) {
  h.style.display = "block";
} else {
  h.style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: you would need to put your if in a function and call it every time you call one of the other functions that changes the value of `countHomePoints`.  Also not sure why in your top code you have `>>>`

Answer (score 0):

### Basic Solution

This was essentially mentioned in a comment, but the issue is that the code that checks if a team's points are greater than 29 only *runs once*, when the page/script is loaded. So as the points increase, that `if` statement never runs again.

The easiest solution is to set that `if` statement inside of its own function and call that function each time the points increase.

```js
let homePoints = document.getElementById("homep");
let guestPoints = document.getElementById("guestp");
let counthomePoints = 0;
let countguestPoints = 0;
var h = document.getElementById("hw");
var g = document.getElementById("gw");

function haddone() {
  counthomePoints += 1;
  homePoints.textContent = counthomePoints;
  checkHomeWin();
}
function haddtwo() {
  counthomePoints += 2;
  homePoints.textContent = counthomePoints;
  checkHomeWin();
}
function haddthree() {
  counthomePoints += 3;
  homePoints.textContent = counthomePoints;
  checkHomeWin();
}
function gaddone() {
  countguestPoints += 1;
  guestPoints.textContent = countguestPoints;
  checkGuestWin();
}
function gaddtwo() {
  countguestPoints += 2;
  guestPoints.textContent = countguestPoints;
  checkGuestWin();
}
function gaddthree() {
  countguestPoints += 3;
  guestPoints.textContent = countguestPoints;
  checkGuestWin();
}

function res() {
  counthomePoints = 0;
  countguestPoints = 0;
  guestPoints.textContent = 0;
  homePoints.textContent = 0;
}

function checkHomeWin() {
  if (counthomePoints > 29) {
    h.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    h.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function checkGuestWin() {
  if (countguestPoints > 29) {
    g.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    g.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

### Optimized Solution

There is no HTML to have a [***minimal reproducible example***](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so I'm not sure exactly how your page is set up but another thing would be the repeated code to increase a team's points. You could actually merge all of that into 1 function that you call. This is basically the difference between [WET and DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) code.

In this example, instead of calling `haddtwo()` you would call `_AddPoints('home', 2)`. This second example also uses a [conditional/ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to show or hide the crown for each team based on whether or not they have 30+ points rather than a traditional `if else` statement. It functions the same but is a little nicer to look at.

```js
const homePoints = document.getElementById("homep"),
guestPoints = document.getElementById("guestp"),
h = document.getElementById("hw"),
g = document.getElementById("gw")

let counthomePoints = 0,
countguestPoints = 0

const _AddPoints = (team, points) => {
  if(team == "home") {
    counthomePoints += points
    homePoints.textContent = counthomePoints
  } else {
    countguestPoints += points
    guestPoints.textContent = countguestPoints
  }
  _CheckWin()
}

const _CheckWin = () => {
  h.style.display = (counthomePoints > 29) ? "block" : "none"
  g.style.display = (countguestPoints > 29) ? "block" : "none"
}

const res = () => {
  counthomePoints = 0
  countguestPoints = 0
  guestPoints.textContent = 0
  homePoints.textContent = 0
}
```